# Select2 multiselect only returns the first selected item

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a configuration form with several multiselect tags using select2. The selected options show correctly when using `$('#selectitem').select2('data');`, but when submitting the form, only the first selected item is being passed.

snippet (this is in a jinja2 template, a Flask app, with UiKit3):

```
<form action="" method="post">
...
                        {% if param['param_type'] == 'list' %}
                          <select id="{{'node_%s' % param['node_id']}}" name="{{'node_%s' % param['node_id']}}" multiple='multiple' class="uk-select uk-form-width-large">
                            {% for p in param['param_value'] %}
                              <option value='{{ p }}'>{{ p }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                          </select>
                        {% else %}
                          <textarea id="{{'node_%s' % param['node_id']}}" name="{{'node_%s' % param['node_id']}}" class='uk-textarea uk-form-width-large'>{{ param['param_value'] }}</textarea>
                        {% endif %}
...
      <button type='submit' name='submit' class='uk-button-default'>Change Settings</button>
</form>
```

and the select2 JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".uk-select").select2({closeOnSelect: false});
  });
```

Everything works as expected, except when I check the returned values, only the first item selected of each multiselect is being passed.

I've tried naming the `name` of the select tag to `name[]` as suggested elsewhere but that had no effect. I've done a lot of searching online for a solution but come up empty.

Answer (score 0):

On selection of a value from dropdown, you can store the selected values into a javascript variable and then pass that variable to the server via ajax call.

Below is example that stores selected values into `ajaxOptions.data.selectedValues` on selection of values from dropdown.

```
var ajaxOptions = {};
var ajaxOptions.data = {};

$(".uk-select").change(function(){
    ajaxOptions.data.selectedValues = $(this).val();
    console.log(ajaxOptions);
  });
```

JsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/g7nkfpca/

**EDITED ANSWER:**

You can use native HTML form submission too. For that first of all, you need to **give the name to select tag in an array format** as below.

```
<select id="{{'node_%s' % param['node_id']}}" name="{{'node_%s' % param['node_id']}}[]" multiple='multiple' class="uk-select uk-form-width-large">
```

And in your PHP code, iterate the `$_POST` data to get all selected options one by one, see code below.

```
// Check if any option is selected 
if(isset($_POST["node_XXX"]))  
{ 
   // Retrieving each selected option 
   foreach ($_POST['node_XXX'] as $node)  
   print "You selected $node<br/>"; 
}
```

In the code above the XXX is the `param['node_id']` that you can replace.

Comment: Thanks. Can I assign that value to the select object so that it's passed when the form is submitted as normal? Otherwise I have to manually collect the values of all the fields (there are many and they're dynamically created) and do an ajax call with the form instead of just using the standard html form (which is the reason for using Select2 in the first place).

Comment: @user11075824, based on your comment I have updated my answer, please see my updated answer, hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add brackets to the name of element:

```
<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" data-plugin="select2" id="id_country" name="id_country[]" required="">
```

You have it in the array then.